# How work in team with Asp.Net MVC 2 project.. Do I need svn ?

Tags: svn, asp.net-mvc-2

What is the best solution to work in team for a MVC2 Project.

I Know I could use SVN to versionning everything.
The problem with svn is we can work together on the same file and make conflict in commit action. 
Is it possible to lock a file in svn to prevent working on the same file ?

Is SVN is a good tool to use in a .Net Project?

I have find a partner who will develop with me on my project. I don't know much about this person. What is the best way to share an asp.net project without giving to him the entire ?.

1- What software should I use to share my project
2- If possiblie, how can I share only some files to my helper programmer?. (Maybe with Remote Desktop ?)

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be fairly new to version control. I suggest you read this [article presenting an introduction to version control systems](http://guides.beanstalkapp.com/version-control/intro-to-version-control.html). It will help you understand how to use them effectively. It also goes over the difference between centralized and distributed systems, so you will be able to make a better choice for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of SC providers out there, SVN, Perforce, TFS, SourceSafe to name but a few. Each has its own pro's/con's. Best read up on them all and decide which is best for you. Only you can answer that question. Personally I prefer Mercurial, but to each his own.

Update:
p.s. You might want to read up on the different types of SC i.e. distributed vs central

[Comparison between Centralized and Distributed Version Control Systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111031/comparison-between-centralized-and-distributed-version-control-systems)

Comment: Good Link, let me verify that and get you back soon

Answer (score 0):

SVN is great for .NET development.  As long as you commit small amounts regularly, you will have possibilities to very few conflicts. You could use Source Safe, if you don't want multiple checkouts, but I think that it is bad idea, if nothing else it may cause you to check in infrequently.

Answer (score 0):

Personnaly I am using GIT for about 2 years, both at work and at home, I think this is the best SCM at the moment, there are a lot of OSS .NET stuff on Github and CodePlex is now supporting GIT, so I think this is a nice pick.

Comment: un Ouellet sa a toujours raison. Je regarde sa (A ouellet has always right)

Comment: @Jean-Francois - [Méfiez-vous des Git](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/114249/git-what-gotchas-should-newcomers-to-version-control-be-aware-of/114312#114312) as first VCS

Answer (score 0):

Consider **[TFS Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us/downloads#tfs-express)** (currently in beta) - a free collaboration server for up to five developers. Provides source code control, work item tracking, and build automation.

Answer (score 0):

SVN supports security configuration at the directory level. [SVN per directory permission](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.authz.perdir) Git is a good tool for sure, but a centralized version control system might suit you better.