# Automatic project build version number

Tags: php, web, build-automation, versioning

I'm building web application based on PHP. (But my question is not related with PHP at all. I need something for all my projects, not only web.)

I'm doing fixes, changes to this application everyday. What I need is, something like versioning system that automatically gives build version number to project and asks me to note changes. What can use for this purpose?

I have no git server and it's not public project so I can use something like gitHub.

Specs of my computer:

**Editor:** Sublime (can use netbeans too if there is any solution for my need)

**OS:** Windows 8

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track. You need to use a VCS **(Version Control System)** such as Git, SVN, or Mercurial. I prefer Git (but use SVN at work). You don't have to have Git projects be public...you can host your own repository locally, [set it up using DropBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960799/using-gitdropbox-together-effectively), or use something like [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/).

There are two major types of version control: Distributed and Centralized. The difference is explained well here: [Comparison between Centralized and Distributed Version Control Systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111031/comparison-between-centralized-and-distributed-version-control-systems)

The "ask me to note changes" is called a **commit** and occurs when you want to take a "snapshot" of your code and assign it a unique identifier (i.e. version number). The way some systems, such as Git, handle "version numbers" is a hash identifier which doesn't translate well like v.2.3.45. You have some options though using tags for version releases and can use a script to generate a revision number. Read more here: [what is the git equivalent for revision number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120001/what-is-the-git-equivalent-for-revision-number)

Comment: Most IDEs will have modules that integrate version control into the IDE environment. I use Eclipse with [EGit](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/), and quite like it.

Comment: If you have time, Can you help me to do this with netbeans and dropbox? I need help really. I can provide teamviewer id and pass so you can remotely help

Comment: @epic_syntax Sorry, I'm not able to at the moment. I'd suggest seeing if anybody in the chat can help: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/