# Eclipse Repository

Tags: eclipse, version-control

Is there any on line repository for Eclipse IDE. We are working on a web development project and its very difficult to integrate everyone's code by carrying around in a pendrive or mailing it.

Comment: If you are looking for a version control system, see for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/77485/what-are-the-relative-strengths-and-weaknesses-of-git-mercurial-and-bazaar

Comment: And this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35465/easy-simple-online-source-control

Answer (score 0):

Nope!

But you can use:

- [SVN](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/)
- [GIT](http://www.eclipse.org/resources/resource.php?id=528)
- [CVS](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/platform-cvs/)

And tons of other version control tools with other repositories online

Answer (score 0):

To add to BoredAndroidDeveloper's answer - you can also use the mentioned version control tools as a service, sparing you the administration and granting global access :

Some of the most prominent are:

[GitHub](https://github.com/) for Git (and others)
[Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) for [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) (and others)